# PHP prepare statement insert too many in foreach

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, foreach, prepared-statement

in my input text i just input

> biografi,

it's should only insert 1 row,

but it's insert 5 times (maybe from this -> my category table contain 5 category)

if i input

> bigrafi,dictionary,

its insert 10 times

```
$categories = explode(",", $kategori);
    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO book_category (idbook, idcategory)
                                    SELECT book.idbook, category.idcategory
                                    FROM book, category
                                    WHERE book.isbn = ?
                                    AND category.nmcategory = ?");
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if (empty($category) || $category == "") {
            continue;
        }

        $stmt2->bind_param("si", $isbn, $category);
        if($stmt2->execute()) {

        } else {
            showAlert("Error when insert category");
        }
    }
    $stmt2->close();
```

its should only insert biografi(3) id to book_category table

```
idbook | idcategory
    8 | 3
```

but its insert 5 times

```
idbook | idcategory
    8 | 1
    8 | 2
    8 | 3
    8 | 4
    8 | 5
```

[image]

sorry for bad explanation, i can't speak english well.
i hope u understand what i mean

SELECT idcategory, nmcategory FROM category

```
| idcategory | nmcategory |
| 1          | kamus      |
| 2          | agama      |
| 3          | biografi   |
| 4          | novel      |
| 5          | komik      |
```

SELECT idbook, isbn FROM book

```
| idbook | isbn |
| 1      | 111  |
```

Comment: It looks like you have no joining condition between `book, category` which results in a cartesian product. Please post the structures of those tables so we can see what column is common between them.

Comment: You're using a `foreach` over `1,2,3,4,5`. And that's why it inserts multiple rows. Check your input list `$kategori`. Change it if doesn't match your expectations.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski im already insert the structure, please see it again

Comment: @mario im just input "biografi," its should only match 1 category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning two separate pieces of information from two tables --  the requested `isbn` and the requested `category` are not related (you are *creating* their relationship by inserting into `book_category`), and so doing a join query as you have done without a joining condition results in a cartesian product (all books multiplied by all categories).  Since there are 5 total rows in the `categories` table, all 5 are returned .

You can instead structure the query with two subselects - one querying `book` and the other querying `category`.  Each subselect will return exactly one value, and the two will be combined together into a single row.

```
// The query reduces to "(SELECT book), (SELECT category)" as separate
// actions, which can be done together as subselects
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO book_category (idbook, idcategory)
    SELECT
     (SELECT idbook FROM book WHERE isbn = ?) AS idbook,
     (SELECT idcategory FROM category WHERE nmcategory = ?) AS idcategory");

// Your bind/execute/fetch can remain the same
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if (empty($category)) {
        continue;
    }

    $stmt2->bind_param("si", $isbn, $category);
    if($stmt2->execute()) {

    } else {
        showAlert("Error when insert category");
    }
}
$stmt2->close();
```

Comment: thanks but i get error when change it
"Error when insert category"

Comment: @anonprophet Place it inside as `showAlert("Error with insert " . $mysqli->error);`

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: So you must have a duplicate category name or a duplicate isbn in your table @anonprophet

Comment: @anonprophet Check your tables. If you `SELECT idbook FROM book WHERE isbn = 'xxxxxx'` and `SELECT idcategory FROM category WHERE nmcateogory='biografi'` does each return exactly one row?  Your MySQL version may permit a `LIMIT 1` inside the subselect but older versions did not support it.

Comment: im already truncate table book, book_category and not found duplicate category. the error still same.
thanks try to help

Comment: Please post the query output from `select idbook, isbn FROM book` and `SELECT idcategory, nmcategory FROM category`

Comment: @anonprophet If you do not have duplicates, my query will work - here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec97d6/1  If you do have duplicates, you can add a `LIMIT 1` into the subselects: `SELECT
     (SELECT idbook FROM book WHERE isbn = ? LIMIT 1) AS idbook,
     (SELECT idcategory FROM category WHERE nmcategory = ? LIMIT 1) AS idcategory`

Comment: Berkowsi im already update, please see it again. there are no duplicate category or isbn in my table.

Comment: @anonprophet I see - here is the demo using your data - it works correctly. Please ensure your code is exactly as I  have posted it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4a1f/1